# Details of header info for a video file format

Tags: iphone, nsmutabledata

I need to append 2 video files by appending their NSMutableData as I have already done this with audio files and it is done correctly but not with video files.

It may be because data bytes contain some header info and I will need to remove these bytes from the 2nd video but I don't know that how many bytes should I remove?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told us the file format in question, but generally:

Look up the specification for the file format in question and find out what the header looks like. Then code a solution based on this information.

There are many resources on the net with file format information, but one place you might want to look is http://www.wotsit.org/.

Comment: The videos are in .MOV format , recorded by UIImagePickerController.